# ngDialog doesn't show data in template

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

When I call ngDialog no information that is in the template is displayed. It arrives to the DOM, but it isn't displayed.

This is the function where it is called:

```
controller.showPlan = function (plan) {
    ngDialog.open({
        template: 'client/src/organizer/app/planner/plan.html',
        scope: $scope.this
    });
};
```

This is the template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template">
<div class="ngdialog-message">
    <h1>Template heading</h1>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
```

This is the place in the main template where it is called:

```
<label ng-if="Planner.hasPlan(plan)" ng-click="Planner.showPlan(plan)">{{plan.title}}</label>
```

Everything works except ngDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `id` to your `text/ng-template` that matches the `url` of the template. So this template will be written to `$templateCache` with the name `client/src/organizer/app/planner/plan.html` & when you request the template it will be read from there (`$templateCache`).

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="client/src/organizer/app/planner/plan.html">
    <div class="ngdialog-message">
        <h1>Template heading</h1>
        <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: For some reason, everytime I reload the page the dialog is empty, until I close the dialog and open it again. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse may I know where you have this `script` template?

Comment: Under: _client/src/organizer/app/planner/_

Comment: @HermanTheGermanHesse have this html on your `index.html` page, so that `$templateCache` will get filled with template content before only.

Comment: You mean that I write it in the index.html so that it is written exactly once to the cache?

Comment: No, to make template available at bootstrap time